# Cannot connect to the internet after enabling ufw

Tags: server, ufw, linux-headers

Having installed UFW on my ubuntu server. I disabled all incoming, enabled all out going, ssh, http and https. Finally, I enabled ufw. However, all commands the requires the internet failed. sudo apt update, ping 8.8.8.8 and curl command failed. But all those commands worked after i disabled ufw.

Please, what am i not doing rightly

I tried ping 8.8.8.8 which failed. everything works fine whenever i disabled ufw.